# Migration from legacy version to newer version or MySQL

Tags: odbc, sqlanywhere

I recently dug up a very old SQL Anywhere database. I have it installed and it kind of works, its only the distributed side of the data, so everything's running via dbeng50 and ODBC.

I would like to migrate this data to MySQL. Is there a way to do this? I attempted to view the data using an ODBC tool but I kept getting error messages saying the ODBC driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior.

I guess the database is too old (it's from 1997) - that put's at it [SQL Anywhere version 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Anywhere#History).

Its also difficult to find the old SQL tools that would help me access these.

Is it possible to use the .db file with a newer version?

Any help or guidance at all would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how it can be done but you can also check out the Sql Anywhere Forum (http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/), where someone from the Sql Anywhere team might help.